# TypeScript and Firebase cloud functions: object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a Firebase cloud function using TypeScript. I have the following code using a promise:

```
        const pro_books = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            resolve(db.child("Books").orderByChild("avg_rating").limitToFirst(15));       
        })
        pro_books
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Recommendations:   Error loading books");

        })
        .then((list_book) => {
            book_id_arr = (list_book).map((x:string)=>{
                const book:Book = JSON.parse(x);
                return book.id;
            })
        }).catch(() => 'obligatory catch');
```

The problem is with the mapping function, in particular for list_book (in the first line inside the try block) and the error I get (during build) is "Object is of type 'unknown'".
list_book is supposed to be the result from the query I run, so it's probably some sort of array of JSON documents, I tried enforcing a type but I can't figure out exactly how to do it, and which type to use.

EDIT: book_id_arr is previously defined as `let book_id_arr:String[] = new Array();`

Comment: Shouldn't the `book_id_arr` be a const or something?

Comment: It is, sorry I didn't notice I didn't include this line

Comment: Okay, why are you wrapping list_book with '()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.child("Books").orderByChild("avg_rating").limitToFirst(15)` is **not** the **result** of a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query). It is just the declaration of the Query.

If you want to get the result, you need to either call the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method or [set a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#on-snapshot).

In your case, you should use the `get()` method, which returns a Promise that will resolve with a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html), so you don't need to wrap it in a new Promise.

If you want to use `map()` on the resulting `QuerySnapshot`, you need to call its `docs` property, which returns "an array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot".

The following should do the trick:

```
    const pro_books_query = db.child("Books").orderByChild("avg_rating").limitToFirst(15);       
    return pro_books_query.get()
    .then((list_book) => {
        book_id_arr = list_book.docs.map(...);
        return ...
    })
    .catch(err => 
        console.log("Recommendations: Error loading books - " + err);
        return null;
    );
```

Comment: Also, depending on how they've structured their data, the map could be simplified to `book_id_arr = list_book.docs.map(doc => doc.id);` and if they care about efficiency, `let book_id_arr = []; list_book.forEach(doc => book_id_arr.push(doc.id)); return book_id_arr;`

Comment: Now it gives me "Property get does not exist on type Query". Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you call it. `get` is a method, not a property, so you should do `get()`, see the answer.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I wrote it exactly as you did. maybe I need to import a library?

Comment: How do you declare `db`? In a Cloud Function, you should use the Admin SDKand therefore you should do `const db = admin.firestore();`. If this doesn't solve your problem, please share the entire code of your Cloud Function (modify your question by adding the code).

Comment: That might be the problem. Thanks!